# Can't find CollectionViewSource using FindResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my XAML code I have defined a CollectionViewSource as a grid resource:

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AgentsViewSource"
                          Source="{StaticResource Agents}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="ID" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Further down as a child of a toolbox which again is a child of the grid I have a ComboBox which should change the SortDescription

```
<ComboBox Name="SortOrderBox" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableProperties}" SelectionChanged="newSortOrder_OnSelectionChanged" Width="130" FontSize="15"/>
```

With the following code behind:

```
private void newSortOrder_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newSortOrder = (string) SortOrderBox.SelectedItem;
        var sortDescription = new SortDescription(newSortOrder, ListSortDirection.Descending);

        var source = (CollectionViewSource) FindResource("AgentsViewSource");

        source.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        source.SortDescriptions.Add(sortDescription);
    }
```

However, when I try to use FindResource I always get an exception. I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong, so all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find resource under window/userControl resources.

Set **`x:Name`** on grid and ***call FindResource on grid instance*** because it is declared as a resource under grid and not under window/UserControl.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
   .....
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
grid.FindResource("AgentViewSource")
```